# Writing spreadsheet to a blob column and retrieving it back using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, blob

We have a requirement to store the uploaded spreadsheet in an Oracle database blob column.
User will upload the spreadsheet using the ADF UI and the same spreadsheet will be persisted to the DB and retrieved later.
We are using POI to process the spreadsheet.
The uploaded file is converted to byte[] and sent to the appserver. Appserver persists the same to the blob column.
But when I am trying to retrieve the same later,I am seeing "Excel found unreadable content in *****.xlsx.Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?" message.
I could resolve this issue by
Converting the byte[] to XSSFWorkbook and converting the same back to byte[] and persisting it.
But according to my requirement I may get very large spreadsheet and initializing XSSFWorkbook might result into outofmemory issues.
The code to get the byte[] from the uploaded spreadsheet is as below

```
 if (uploadedFile != null) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new         ByteArrayOutputStream();
                inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
                int c = 0;
                while (c != -1) {
                    c = inputStream.read();
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write((char) c);
                }
                bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            }
```

and the same byte[] is being persisted into a blob column as below.
1. Assign this byte[] to the BlobCloumn
2. Update the SQL Update statement with the bolobColumn
3. Execute the Statement.

Once the above step is done, retrieve the spreadsheet as follows.
1. Read the BlobColumn 
2. Get the bytes[] from the BlobColumn
3. Set the content-type of the response to support the spreadsheet.
4. Send the byte[].

But when I open the above downloaded spreadsheet I am getting the spreadsheet corrupted error.

If I introduce an additional step as below after receiving the byte[] from the UI, the issue is solved.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedSpreadSheetBytes);
     XSSFWorkbook uploadedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

and then, derive the byte[] again from the XSSFWorkbook as below

```
byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] spreadSheetBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

I feel converting the byte[] to XSSFWorkbook and then converting the XSSFWorkbook back to byte[] is redundant.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: There is corruption being introduced somewhere, but it is unclear what your process is. Could you spell it out one step at a time, and then tell us where the error occurs? Include specifics on how the spreadsheet is persisted, and by which process. Same for conversions: how are you doing that, and what process is doing it. My initial thought is that POI writes to an `OutputStream`, maybe a `ByteArrayOutputStream` would work with `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The memory issues can be avoided by, instead of initializing the entire XSSFWorkbook, using event-based parsing (SAX). This way, you are only processing parts of the file which consumes less memory. See [the POI spreadsheet how-to page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) for more info on SAX parsing.
You could also increase the JVM memory, but that's no guarantee of course.

Comment: We tried that for reading the spreadsheet. But the case here is just writing the byte[] to the DB. If we write the byte[] as they are coming from the UI we are seeing the corrupted spreadsheet message while opening the spreadsheet. Instead if we convert the byte[] to the XSSFWorkbook and get the bytes[] back and write them to DB no issues are observed.

Comment: How are you converting the byte[] to XSSFWorkbook? Could be something going wrong with character encodings, file headers, ..
I'm guessing the process of converting to XSFFWorkbook adds some necessary bytes. Compare the sizes of the initial byte[] and the one you have after getting the byte[] back from the XSSFWorkbook.

Comment: @Vasantha:"But the case here is just writing the byte[] to the DB." Yes, but how shall we know how you are doing this? There is not only one possibility to do this and you have not provided any code. Please show the code, which is writing the byte[] to the DB, in your question by editing this question.

Comment: When I closely observe this I found that the byte[] that I am getting out the below block is not of the same size as that of the uploaded spreadsheet.

Comment: if (uploadedFile != null) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new         ByteArrayOutputStream();
                inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
                int c = 0;
                while (c != -1) {
                    c = inputStream.read();
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write((char) c);
                }
                bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            }

Comment: I tried using the IOUtils available in apache commons io but no luck even there